# Slightly vs. slight

Tags: adverbs

In this specific sentence what is the correct use of slightly/slight?

Upgrading the system, even if it was slightly, resulted in...

or

Upgrading the system, even if it was slight, resulted in...

I think it is the first option but I am being told that it is the second one so I'm confused...

Comment: I wouldn't regard either one as correct.

Comment: "Upgrading the system, even if it was slight(ly)" is a hypothetical statement.  Therefore it could not have "resulted in" anything.  It "*might* result" in something, or perhaps even "*will* result" in something.

Comment: @HotLicks Why do you say it is hypothetical? Suppose we determine  that "if" = "though" (which is idiomatically possible), then it becomes something that has actually happened.

Comment: @HotLicks - That's not a hypothetical, any more than is, "Slightly upgrading the system resulted in [etc]."

Comment: @anongoodnurse - "even if it was slightly" makes it hypothetical.

Comment: You're wrong, unless you can only see the hypothetical below. "Slightly upgrading the system resulted in a large improvement in customer experience."– There's nothing hypothetical about it. I think you're being too prescriptive.

Comment: @anongoodnurse - "Even if" makes it hypothetical.

Comment: An antecedent for the pronoun might be a better place to start. And if you really want to stick to this format, I think you need to rescue *resulted* with *did result*.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your answers!
I understand that my sentence had already a very poor construction and your comments really helped me making a better one.

Comment: @HotLicks "He was not badly injured even though he fell off a cliff". Are you saying that is hypothetical? Now substitute "if" for "though". The meaning is the same. In other words "even if" can be used in different senses, one of which renders the substance hypothetical - the other one doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Upgrading the system, even slightly, carries risk.

Slightly is an adverb modifying the verb "upgrading".

**EDIT**

Upgrading the system, even though the changes were slight, resulted in ...

Slight is an adjective.  Take your pick.